# How to add timestamp for artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have following Jenkisfile and I'm trying to upload the artifacts with a timestamp.

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field def timeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().format('YYYYMMdd-hhmmss',TimeZone.getTimeZone('CST'))

node {
stage('Creating some artifacts') {
    sh 'touch hello.txt hi.txt'
}

stage('Uploading artifacts') {
    def server = Artifactory.server ('art-1')
    def uploadSpec = """{
        "files": [
        {
        "pattern": "*.txt",
        "target": "repo1/Dev/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/*.txt.${timeStamp}"
         }
  ]
    }"""
            def buildInfo1 = server.upload(uploadSpec)
            server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo1)
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error while trying this.

```
[consumer_1] Deploying artifact: http://learner.blr.example.com:8081/artifactory/repo1/Dev/12/*.txt.20180913-044451
[Thread consumer_1] An exception occurred during execution:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 500 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
Invalid path. '*' is not a valid name character: repo1/Dev/12/*.txt.20180913-044451 Status code: 500
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:44)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.producerConsumer.ConsumerRunnableBase.run(ConsumerRunnableBase.java:11)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 500 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
Invalid path. '*' is not a valid name character: repo1/Dev/12/*.txt.20180913-044451 Status code: 500
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:692)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:374)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:362)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:39)
    ... 2 more

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.Exception: Error occurred during operation, please refer to logs for more information.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.producerConsumer.ProducerConsumerExecutor.start(ProducerConsumerExecutor.java:84)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecsHelper.uploadArtifactsBySpec(SpecsHelper.java:71)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:190)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed uploading artifacts by spec
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:194)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:131)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1042)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1025)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.executors.GenericUploadExecutor.execution(GenericUploadExecutor.java:52)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.UploadStep$Execution.run(UploadStep.java:65)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.UploadStep$Execution.run(UploadStep.java:46)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Are there any alternative/simple way to add timestamp in artifacts in Jenkins?

P.S.: I'm new to Jenkins groovy scripting and JFrog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that `*` is an invalid character for a file name so I don't think you can use it in the target field. However, the artifactory docs say you can do this instead (links for docs bellow):

```
def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
        {
             "pattern": "(*).txt",
             "target": "repo1/Dev/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/{1}.txt.${timeStamp}"
        }
    ]
```

In this code, `{1}` stands for "whatever got matched inside the first parenthesis in the `pattern`" (every open+close parenthesis in a regex defines a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)).

Note: I don't use artifactory so I didn't test the above code, I am going off of the artifactory docs: 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-UsingPlaceholders

I'd also suggest you move the timestamp to the file name instead of the file extension, so that when you download the file, your computer knows which program to use to open it. So i'd change target to something like:

- files shorted fist by name then by timestamp: `repo1/Dev/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/{1}-${timeStamp}.txt`
- files shorted fist by timestamp then by name:
  `repo1/Dev/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/${timeStamp}-{1}.txt`

Comment: I have checked and it works great. Thanks for the answer and great explanation.