# Add timestamp to war file generated from Node project to artifactory in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jenkins-groovy

I have a `war` file generated from my Jenkins pipeline. I want to publish it to Artifactory. I want to add a timestamp to my `war` file generated onto Artifactory. Is there a way to change `JenkinsFile` in order to reflect the timestamp?

```
def server = Artifactory.newServer url: "https://artifacts.com/artifactory"
buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
    {
        "pattern": "./build/*.war",
        "target": "<path-to-target>"
    }
    } """

    // Upload to Artifactory.
    server.upload spec: uploadSpec, buildInfo: buildInfo
    // Publish build info.
    server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

What changes are required in `JenkinsFile` to include timestamp to the Artifactory?

Comment: This timestamp would be reflected in the artifact metadata or where?

Comment: Artifact name itself

Comment: You can also view the 'build.timestamp' property of the artifact

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions,

1. rename the file before uploading it.

   - If you have only one file and you know its name:

```
sh 'mv toto.war `date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H.%M"`toto.war'
```

- If you have several files you don't know there names

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
for i in *.war; do mv "$i" ${i::-4}`date +"--%d-%m-%Y-%H.%M"`.war; done
'''
```

Here we are using bash to loop through all .war files and move them in order to rename them. `${i::-4}` removes the extension. You can modify the date format by looking at date's man page.

2. use groovy and let target property be the one doing the rename

```
@Field def timeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().format('YYYYMMdd-hhmmss',TimeZone.getTimeZone('CST'))

uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
    {
        "pattern": "./build/*.war",
        "target": "<path-to-target>.${timeStamp}.war"
    }
    } """
```

original post from: 
[How to add timestamp for artifacts in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311426/how-to-add-timestamp-for-artifacts-in-jenkins)

as you mentioned you will have to whitelist the Calendar.getInstance method, getTime and getTimeZone as well

Comment: This solution requires the [Permissive Script Security Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin) to be enabled, which is not possible as I do not want to compromise security for my builds.

Comment: I updated my answer. Command line is indeed often a better solution than Groovy when it comes to jenkins jobs. Groovy is executed on master jenkins, sh commands are executed on slaves, however I personally like the groovy solution here. I am curious about the security vulnerability you are talking about. How whitelisting the Calendar methods do present a security vulnerability?