# Deployment rejected on migrated Artifactory Instance

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, artifactory

We are using Artifactory 6.17.0 on a Linux Server.

We migrated it to a new server by simply tar'ing the installation directory & un-tar'ing it at exactly the same path in the new machine. This directory contains the entire installation.

Retrieval of local & bincentre objects via Artifactory is working ok using maven & pom.xml in a Java project under eclipse.

Deployments are being rejected as follows:

```
2022-02-06 14:48:49,779 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [WARN ] (o.a.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:125) -
Sending HTTP error code 409:
The repository 'libs-release-local' rejected the resolution of an artifact
'libs-release-local:my/server/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/securpharm.server-0.0.1-20220206.134849-1.jar'
due to conflict in the snapshot release handling policy.
```

I have updated the `<distributionManagement>` in my pom.xml to the suggested values fromt the Artifactory Web Admin:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>servername-releases</name>
        <url>http://servername.domain.name.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: The error implies that you are trying to deploy a snapshot version into a repository that is configured to handle releases only. Change the deployment to a snapshot repository, or enable snapshot handling through the repository configuration (via UI or REST API)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [409 conflict in the snapshot release handling policy during artifact deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146892/409-conflict-in-the-snapshot-release-handling-policy-during-artifact-deploy)

Comment: I found this in my pom.xml "<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>". I'd never had an entry with SNAPSHOT in the name before & I've always deployed to "servername-releases" as shown in the extract from my pom.xml, so I assume its figuring out heuristically that its a Snapshot from the text in the version entry & trying to deploy a snapshot as a release?

Comment: Yes, adding `-SNAPSHOT` to a version makes maven treat as a snapshot version.

Comment: Now I'm using a non-snapshot version in the pom it's deploying to the releases-lib ok. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: With pleasure..

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to the above comment, If you would like to publish both snapshot and release version under the repository "**libs-release-local**" repository you can select the option "**Handle Releases**" in the libs-release-local repository configuration page and publish the version. As shown in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwgTv.png).

Please note, it is always recommended to have separate repositories for handling release and snapshot version.